# ios crash issue - NSRange

Tags: ios, exception

I got this error message.

```
GoogleAnalytics 2.0b3 void GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException *)     
(GAIUncaughtExceptionHandler.m:41): Uncaught exception: *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: 
index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]
libc++abi.dylib: terminate_handler unexpectedly threw an exception
```

When I trying to zoom page, I got crash and this error in crashlytics.

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x31a202a3 __exceptionPreprocess + 162
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x3974897f objc_exception_throw + 30
2  CoreFoundation                 0x3196bb75 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 164
3  TestApp                       0x000b1bfb -[EpisodeTableViewDelegate    
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (EpisodeTableViewDelegate.m:155)
4  UIKit                          0x338ea28d -[UITableView 
_selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 876
5  UIKit                          0x3396cf81 -[UITableView 
_userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 156
6  Foundation                     0x3232e277 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 450
7  CoreFoundation                 0x319f55df __
CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
8  CoreFoundation                 0x319f5291 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 272
9  CoreFoundation                 0x319f3f01 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232
10 CoreFoundation                 0x31966ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356
11 CoreFoundation                 0x31966d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
12 GraphicsServices               0x3553f2eb GSEventRunModal + 74
13 UIKit                          0x3387c301 UIApplicationMain + 1120
14 Tapastic                       0x00075cb7 main (main.m:16)
15 Tapastic                       0x000753b8 start
```

My code is as below:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        Episode *episode = [[Episode alloc] init];
        [episode bindProperties:[self.pager.contents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [self.baseController performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_EPISODE_VIEW sender:episode];
    }
}
```

I cannot solve this problem. How can I fix it? If possible, please let know. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `objectAtIndex` on the `episode` array with index 2, when there are only two objects in the array. Array objects are numbered starting with 0, so an array with two objects only has elements 0 and 1.

It sounds like you're not setting up your `UITableView` correctly. If there are only two objects in the array backing the table, there should only be two rows in the table.